# Multiple Table Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have an issue where I need to ONLY get a few things from my initial table, and then join another item from another table, and then join one more item from another table.  I thought this would be easy, but it is far from it.  Here's my SQL information (kept it to one record for simplicity).

```
select * from customers limit 1 \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           CustomerID: 9
       CustomerMapsco: 459
       CustomerActive: 1
    CustomerFirstName: John
     CustomerLastName: Doe
CustomerServiceStreet: 1314 Road Rd.
  CustomerServiceCity: City
 CustomerServiceState: TX
   CustomerServiceZip: 12345
CustomerBillingStreet: 1314 Road Rd.
  CustomerBillingCity: City
 CustomerBillingState: TX
   CustomerBillingZip: 12345
    CustomerHomePhone: 1231231234
    CustomerCellPhone: 1231231234
    CustomerWorkPhone: 1231231234
      CustomerWorkExt: 12345
          CustomerFax: 1231231324
        CustomerEmail: email@tld.COM
          CustomerDog: 0
               CrewID: 1
           ScheduleID: 1
            protected: 1


mysql> select * from customerservice limit 1 \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       CustomerSvcID: 15
          CustomerID: 9
       ServiceTypeID: 1
     FrequencyTypeID: 1
               DayID: 5
     CustomerSvcCost: 21
CustomerSvcBeginDate: 2007-01-01 00:00:00
  CustomerSvcEndDate: NULL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from frequency
    -> ;
+-----------------+---------------+
| FrequencyTypeID | FrequencyType |
+-----------------+---------------+
|               1 | Weekly        |
|               2 | Biweekly      |
|               3 | One Time      |
+-----------------+---------------+
```

What I need is the following columns:

```
customers.CustomerID, customers.CustomerActive, customers.protected, frequency.FrequencyType
```

I figured I'd have to do a triple join to get the FrequencyType from the customerservice table as they only referenced in that table, rather than the customer table.  So therefore, I have to take one extra step to get that information (`customers <> customerservice <> frequency`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you need to join all the three tables to get that information, this should be enough:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerActive, c.protected, f.FrequencyType
FROM customers c
   JOIN customerservice s
      ON c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
   JOIN frequency f
      ON s.FrequencyTypeID = f.FrequencyTypeID
```

Comment: Awesome that solves it.  Is there any way you could explain this for future reference?  I'm guessing that the characters after `FROM tablename` are aliases (`AS`?). What I don't understand is you referenced them like they were already defined in the `SELECT` portion. So, I'm guessing that MySQL (and maybe others) allow you to reference the aliases before you define them, and then as long as you define them, then it's all good?  Just some basic MySQL questions. Again, your solution worked great.

Comment: yes, table t or table as t is just the same. Actually i don't know how mysql parse the query but for sure it looks for (and also SQL Server works that way) alias definiton before interpreter select statement otherwise that won't work. I'm sure someone else could explain that much better tham me

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerActive, c.protected, f.FrequencyType
    FROM customers c
        LEFT JOIN customerservice cs
            INNER JOIN frequency f
                ON cs.FrequencyTypeID = f.FrequencyTypeID
            ON c.CustomerID = cs.CustomerID
```